# Table name with dot in CodeFirst

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I thought that it was a good idea to prefix some of my tables with the name of the area:

```
MyNewSubProject.Table1
MyNewSubProject.Table2
```

Unfortunately when I'm going to map these tables with Entity Framework Code First with the model builder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>().ToTable("MyNewSubProject.Table1");
```

Throws the exception:

```
(System.Data.Entity.Infraestructure.DbUpdateException)
{"Invalid object name 'MyNewSubProject.Table1'."}
```

The table name is correct. I've tried to add the schema but no luck. If I remove the dot everything goes great.

Any way to use the dot?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Do you imagine to see the dot in SQL or in C# ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the DDL commands don't properly wrap the object identifiers.

Try wrapping the Table name in `[MyNewSubProject.Table1]`.

This was a know issue, I assumed this was fixed by now:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/9c5642ad-3e4e-496f-9721-059071d653e3

**UPDATE**

Apparently you can set the schema seperately like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>().ToTable("Table1", "MyNewSubProject");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ntziolis. It seems it is not fixed. Unortunately I've tested all combinations with the schema. I have to say that 'MyNewSubProject' it's just a prefix in the table and not a real schema. If I put in schema 'dbo.MyNewSubProject' or 'MyNewSubProject' doesn't work. It's a bad decission use the dot?. If it's a special character in SQL...

Comment: yes, if you can eliminate the `.` do it, it is bad design to use reserved characters for names

Answer (score 3):

try the following

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>().ToTable("Table1","MyNewSubProject");
```

this will change schema  to MyNewSubProject

Comment: Thanks! Doesn't work :( ... 'MyNewSubProject' it's just a prefix and not a real schema.